# ActionMailer 2.3.5 mangles my zip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, binary, zip, actionmailer

I'm attempting to send email with a zip attachment from rails with ActionMailer 2.3.5.

The zip file is sound on the server (unzips correctly with the unzip utility), but the zip file that comes through to the recipient is corrupted. Also, adding the attachment causes the message body to be omitted from the email.

There's nothing remarkable about the method:

```
attachment :content_type => "application/zip",
      :body => File.read(zip.path),
      :filename => File.basename(zip.path)
```

There's apparently something going awry around File.read. When I pass a string here instead of the file contents, the attachment comes through correctly. Something to do with binary data?

WTF?

Comment: Did a diff on the email attachment and the original zip file. It appears that the end of the file (317 bytes) was truncated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `File.read` treats your file as a text file. (I guess you are trying this on Windows) You have to specify the mode to force it to open your file in binary mode:

```
attachment :content_type => "application/zip",
  :body => File.read(zip.path, mode: 'rb'),
  :filename => File.basename(zip.path)
```

Or in Rails > 3:

```
attachment[File.basename(zip.path)] = File.read(zip.path, mode: 'rb')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include an attachment and keep your body (a multipart mail), you must do something like this:

```
  def email(message)
    setup_mail(message)

    part       :content_type => "text/html", 
               :body => render_message("email", @body)

    attachment :content_type => 'application/zip', 
               :body => File.read(message[:file].path), 
               :filename => File.basename(zip.path)
  end
```

Where "email" is your body template.

Comment: Thanks—this solved the problem of the missing message body. Zip file is still coming through corrupted, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the encoding for the attachment:

```
attachment :content_type => "application/zip",
      :body => File.read(zip.path),
      :filename => File.basename(zip.path),
      :transfer_encoding => 'base64'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, still having an issue with the zip file. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to open your zipfile in binary read mode:

```
:body => File.open(zip.path, 'rb') {|f| f.read}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue in my project. I mixed solutions from "mu is too short" and "fivaiez". Now it works. Thanks a lot for all you guys comments.  The following is my code.

```
def sent(sent_at = Time.now)
  subject    'test attachment mail'
  recipients 'mail-list@company.com'
  from       'please_no_reply@company.com'
  sent_on    sent_at
  content_type "text/html"
  attachment :content_type => 'application/zip',
             :body => File.read("data/sample.zip"),
             :filename => 'sample.zip',
             :transfer_encoding => "base64"    
end
```